# TAG Merge - vcenter vmware-vcenter vsphere-vcenter

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, merge

Shouldn't these 3 tags be merged?

[vcenter](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/vcenter) [vmware-vcenter](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/vmware-vcenter) [vsphere-vcenter](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/vsphere-vcenter)

Comment: You're right, I think we should keep vmware-vcenter as the main.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clearly the populace has settled on $vendor-$product for this particular case. The others should probably be aliases of the one with 80-odd questions.